# LWJGL - Texture Only Shows Solid Color

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, texture-mapping, opengl-3

For some reason, when I try to render textures using LWJGL, the texture only renders as a solid color. I don't think that it's a problem with the texture loading (I'm using the Slick Util library) because the color that the texture is seems to be the dominant color in the image.

Model class:

```
public class Model {

private FloatBuffer vertices, uvValues;
private int vertexID, uvID;
private int vertexAttrib, uvAttrib;

private Texture tex;
private ByteBuffer texData;
private int textureID;
private int textureLocation;

private Matrix4f modelMatrix;
private FloatBuffer modelBuffer;
private int modelMatrixLocation;

public Model(float[] verts, float[] uvs, int modelLocation, String texPath, int texLocation){
    vertices = createBuffer(verts);
    vertexAttrib = 0;
    vertexID = createVBO(vertices, vertexAttrib, 3);

    tex = TextureUtils.loadTexturePNG(texPath);
    texData = createBuffer(tex);
    textureID = bindTextureData(tex, texData);
    textureLocation = texLocation;

    uvValues = createBuffer(uvs);
    uvAttrib = 1;
    uvID = createVBO(uvValues, uvAttrib, 2);

    modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    modelMatrixLocation = modelLocation;
    modelBuffer = createBuffer(modelMatrix);
}

private static FloatBuffer createBuffer(float[] vals){
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vals.length);
    buffer.put(vals);
    buffer.flip();

    return buffer;
}

private static FloatBuffer createBuffer(Matrix4f mat){
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    mat.store(buffer);
    buffer.flip();

    return buffer;
}

private static ByteBuffer createBuffer(Texture tex){
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(tex.getTextureData().length);
    buffer.put(tex.getTextureData());
    buffer.flip();

    return buffer;
}

private static int bindTextureData(Texture tex, ByteBuffer data){
    int id = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, (int) tex.getWidth(), (int) tex.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    return id;
}

private static int createVBO(FloatBuffer buffer, int location, int vectorSize){
    int id = glGenBuffers();

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(location, vectorSize, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(location);

    return id;
}

private void bind(){
    glUniformMatrix4(modelMatrixLocation, false, modelBuffer);

    tex.bind();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttrib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvAttrib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(uvAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}

private void unbind(){
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvAttrib);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttrib);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

public void render(){
    bind();

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.capacity() / 3);

    unbind();
}

}
```

Model initialization code:

```
        model = new Model(new float[]{
        -1, -1, -3,
        1, -1, -3,
        1, 1, -3
    }, new float[]{
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f
    }, program.getUniformLocation("model_matrix"), "res/tex/testTex.png", program.getUniformLocation("texture_sampler"));
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

 layout(location = 0) in vec3 position_modelspace;

layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertex_UV;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

out vec2 UV;

void main(){
vec4 vertex_MVP = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(position_modelspace, 1.0);
gl_Position = vertex_MVP;

UV = vertex_UV;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D texture_sampler;

in vec2 UV;

out vec3 color;

void main(){
color = texture(texture_sampler, UV).rgb;
}
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is. The texture loads without any problem, and I've looked at a lot of other questions with similar problems, but I haven't yet found one that solves this.

Comment: What does the implementation of this `Texture` class look like, and why are you binding it ***before*** you set the active Texture Image Unit? I would expect to see `tex` object bound at the same time as `glBindTexture (...)`, in fact I suspect they do the same thing.

Comment: I'm using the Slick Util library's Texture class. I removed tex.bind(), but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I didn't think it would, but the stray bind seemed odd. Also, your `createVBO (...)` method does some superfluous things such as enabling an immediately disabling attribute pointers. Whether a pointer is enabled or disabled only really matters at the time you call `glDrawArrays (...)`. That state does not affect anything else. Likewise, there is no harm in keeping the VBO bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Binding **0** is unnecessary unless you use non-VBO based vertex arrays.

Comment: I looked at the code, and haven't spotted the problem. We can try to narrow down the problem it that works for you. First experiment: Output a fixed color from the fragment shader. Change the code line in the shader to `color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);`. Do you see a yellow triangle? If yes, change it to `color = vec3(UV, 0.0);`. Does the triangle now display a red/green/yellow gradient? This will tell us if the geometry is rendered correctly, and the texture coordinates reach the fragment shader successfully.

Comment: The second time didn't work! For some reason, it seems that the UV coordinates aren't reaching the shader.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed the UV coordinates, and it shows a gradient, but when I try to use textures, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm curious, what was wrong with the UV coordinates? I'm having similar issues (I'm not using the Slick library, but my textures show a solid colour, seemingly blended from the texture image.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe adding`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` might solve the problem

Comment: The `GL_TEXTURE_...` enable is _only_ required for the fixed-function pipeline and has no effect when shaders are used. In core profile GL, calling this would result just in an error.